# Pre-install and pre-activate wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am trying to pre-install and pre-activate WordPress plugin(s) for my users.

The problem: I cannot fully setup the WordPress'es for them. Just setup database connection params, nothing more.

So using wp-cli is not possible, it requires to have the wp core to be installed.

Is there any way to pre-install and (!) pre-activate plugins using their default params?

Answer (score 0):

make a folder "mu-plugins" in wp-content directory and put the plugin files in this folder you want to pre activated.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** Use Wordpress multisite, and network activate the plugins you want

**Option 2:** In wp-config setup a default theme `define( 'WP_DEFAULT_THEME', 'twentyseventeen' );`

In the default theme bundle in your plugins, and include them in your plugins folder.

```
include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
activate_plugin( 'contact-form-7/wp-contact-form-7.php' );
```